# String to sqlsyntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

I have a string:

```
string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
```

But I dont know how to add the string to this sqlsnytax

```
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] != null) 
        {
            string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
            Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(theUserId);


        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=x; Password=x;");
        cn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT User.FirstName, User.SecondName, User.Aboutme, User.DOB, Pictures.picturepath FROM User LEFT JOIN Pictures ON User.UserID = Pictures.UserID WHERE User.UserID=@UserID"), cn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", theUserId);

        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Name.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
            Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));
            Age.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(3));
            Image1.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(4));
        }


    }
}
}
```

`User.UserID=1` how would I change that to something like `User.UserID="theUserId"`

Comment: @Brandon has the correct answer given the requirements; however, a couple things should be noted.  First, "theUserId" needs to be sanitized prior to execution.  As it stands this has SQL injection written all over it.  Second, I'm not sure what it is you are passing this too but it sure looks like someone needs to rip it out.  You might want to post some of the code over at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ukhardy, deleted. WraithNath essentially has the same answer without all the noise. I removed mine and upvoted his instead.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I will follow suit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the following.  The number one thing to note is the USING clauses which will clean up your connections.  Either you use these or you have to wrap everything in try .. catches with the appropriate disposing calls made.

```
if (Session["UserID"] != null) 
{
    string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
    Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(theUserId);

    using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=root; Password=commando;")) {
        cn.Open();
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT User.FirstName, User.SecondName, User.Aboutme, User.DOB, Pictures.picturepath FROM User LEFT JOIN Pictures ON User.UserID = Pictures.UserID WHERE User.UserID=@UserID", cn)) {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", theUserId);

            using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Name.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
                    Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));
                    Age.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(3));
                    Image1.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(4));
                }
            } // using reader
        } // using cmd
    } // using connection
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string theUserId = Session[ "UserID" ].ToString();

OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(
      "SELECT User.FirstName, User.SecondName, User.Aboutme, User.DOB, Pictures.picturepath FROM User LEFT JOIN Pictures ON User.UserID = Pictures.UserID WHERE User.UserID=@UserID" 
    ), cn);

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", theUserId);
```

You can define your parameters with @Parameter name and then add them using .Parameters.AddWithValue

This is much safer than string.format or concatinating the string yourself

Comment: im getting an error on the line ,cn); its really strange because this was working be4 I added in my string to it? iv re edited so you can see

Comment: @Garrith, no, it wasn't working before. In the sample you posted you have an extra closing `)` after your string. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WHERE User.UserID = $UserID
```

Then add a parameter called '$UserID' to the Command object you're using, and it will pick up the value when you execute the query.

Note that I'm not sure what driver you're using for MySQL, I *think* parameters must be prefixed with `$`, but I'm not 100% sure. In SQL Server it's `@`.

Comment: The question is tagged with `MySQL`. There are managed MySQL drivers for .NET, which I've used before. I assumed the poster is using MySQL.

Comment: True.  However the $UserId notation is php specific and not MySql syntax.  MySql uses the same variable syntax that other RDBMs use.  For example: @UserId See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html for a little more information

Comment: It's not PHP-specific. Back in the 1.1 days the MySQL driver sponsored by MySQL AB required something other than a `@` character. I just don't remember which one it was. If they standardized it to be `@` then that's great. It's been a while.

Comment: @kprobst: I'll make you a deal.  If you can point to *any* MySQL documentation that uses the $ notation for variables that isn't participating in php string replacement, no matter the version, then I will happily eat crow and change my vote. ;)

Comment: That ain't gonna happen, sorry. I don't care enough about your vote to waste my time digging for something you claim I'm making up. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

string.Format("SELECT User.FirstName, User.SecondName, User.Aboutme, User.DOB, Pictures.picturepath FROM User LEFT JOIN Pictures ON User.UserID = Pictures.UserID WHERE User.UserID={0}", theUserId);